# SQL use result in same query as variable

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
users (id, email)
devices (id,name, userid)
```

I want to insert a new device on insert ther userid based on the email in the users table:

```
INSERT INTO devices (name, userid) VALUES ('devicename', retrievedUserId)
```

How can I pass the id from the users table to above query?

```
SELECT id from users WHERE email = 'xxx@xxx.com'
```

I would like something like this:

```
INSERT INTO devices (name, userid) VALUES ('devicename', SELECT id from users WHERE email = 'xxx@xxx.com')
```

But with correct syntax :) It has been a while since I wrote vanilla SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO devices (name, userid)  
SELECT 'devicename',id from users WHERE email = 'xxx@xxx.com'
```